# Pyspark Using to Generate Hive Table count to print the reports as a csv file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql

I am new to pyspark development but I got requirement to develop the pyspark code to generate reports some path in csv file. in that csv file.

in that CSV file, we needs to show the data for each table counts on daily basis.

fine data frame to print in single csv file.

Kindly help me.

Comment: your question is not clear, you need to give more information like what is your input and what are your expected output.

also try to put something what you tried so far.

Comment: i have to calculate each table daily counts and put to csv file with header like as table name. so that my reports will provide the information daily basis  data loaded each table how many counts. this is my expectation. how do we do it using pyspark.

Comment: my expectation is , i have calculate each day how many counts needed in table.. like today and D-1,D-2 counts

Comment: I dont know if i understand your question correctly, basically if you have a dataframe( after reading the table), then you can simply get the count as `df.count()`

Comment: I have 1000 tables, each table i can do count but needs to generate single CSV file needs to generate. any samples. kindly provide